# Customize the devise edit method - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have a problem with customising Devise method. I want to edit an existing profile. But it doesn't change.
Here's my code
My controller:

```
class DashboardController < Users::RegistrationsController::ApplicationController

  def index
  end

  def update
    @user = current_user
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
        redirect_to 'index', :notice  => "Successfully updated profile."
    else
        Rails.logger.info(@user.errors.messages.inspect)
        render :action => 'edit'
    end
  end

  def edit  
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:avatar, :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end

end
```

My edit view

```
    <div class="container sign-in-up">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
      <br>
<div class="text-center">
  <h1><b>Edit the profile</b> </h2>
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="new">
      <fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="right-inner-addon">
                <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                <%= form_for current_user, url: edit_dashboard_path(current_user), html: { method: :get, multipart: true }  do |f|%>
             <div class="home_field " >
               <%= f.label :username%>
               <br/>
               <%= f.text_field :username, autofocus: true, :placeholder => 'Username', class:"form-control input-lg " %>
            </div>
            <div class="home_field  ">
              <%= f.label :email %>
              <br/>
             <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, :placeholder => 'Email' , class:"form-control input-lg" %>
            </div>

            <div class="home_field ">
              <%=  f.label :password%>
              <br/>
              <%= f.password_field :password, :placeholder => 'Password', class:"form-control input-lg"%>
            </div>

            <div class="home_field ">
              <%= f.label :password_confirmation%>
              <br/>
              <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation,:placeholder => 'Confirm your password' , class:"form-control input-lg"%>
            </div>
            <div class ="home_field">
              <%= f.file_field :avatar  %>
              <br>
            </div>

          <div>
        </div>
         <div class="home_field">
            <%= f.submit 'Edit the profile', class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block  btn-group" %>
             <br/>
         </div>
            <% end %>
        </fieldset>
```

It can be a problem in my layout code, where i make the link to the edit page

```
<%= link_to "Edit the Profile", edit_dashboard_path %>
```

Comment: What exactly is not change?Is anything in the Rails log file? Maybe errors?

Answer (score 0):

Your form is submitting to the edit dashboard using a get, which is the same page you are on.  Instead you want to update the current user something like this:

```
<%= form_for current_user, html: { multipart: true }  do |f|%>
```

This will default to the update attribute and CRUD action defined in your routes file for a user

Comment: I made it just like this, but i received the another error message : Showing /home/vladislav/Testing/app_test/app/views/dashboard/edit.html.erb where line #13 raised:

undefined method `user_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fe0e74404d8>:0x007fe0e74121a0>

Comment: ah okay, you need to find the controller and method in your routes file that updates your users.  If this controller actually updates the user, then you just need to change the method to put or patch, but I would actually make your users controller to perform crud actions on the user and not use this controller for that purpose

Comment: http://s35-temporary-files.radikal.ru/9852efcb45344f358c5fdbe910740bbc/-88693455.png

Comment: I'm new at rails, so i'd ask for your help. How do i change the method from 'get' to the 'put'(i suggest i need 'put')

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest changing this line:

```
<%= form_for current_user, url: edit_dashboard_path(current_user), html: { method: :get, multipart: true }  do |f|%>
```

1. In the url use your path to the 'update' method, not the edit (use `rake routes` on your command line)
2. In the method use :put instead of :get

Comment: see my response as well, the method needs to change, but so does the url

Comment: use 'rake routes' on your command line to show you a list of routes
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#inspecting-and-testing-routes

use grep to narrow it down. eg 'rake routes | grep update'

Comment: rake routes i know, but how can i put it in my ruby code ?

Comment: so what is the output of rake routes for the update method then?